# Query date not working properly

Tags: sql, postgresql

As I fixed my previous question about a function, I am stuck into my query.

```
SELECT * FROM threads WHERE cat_id = :cat_id AND thread_date=(
    SELECT max(thread_date) FROM threads
```

If the column in the database has the same thread_date as in another column, it prints the first thread_name out instead of just both.

I want to print both thread_name out of a cat_id as clearly said above.

```
Example data: id = 1, cat_id = 15, thread_name = test, thread_date = 15;
              id = 2, cat_id = 16, thread_name = test2, thread_date = 15;
```

Result:

```
test test
```

What I expect:

```
test 
test2
```

Thanks

http://image.prntscr.com/image/1c44540d40fa413f8bd073bc481858b9.png

Comment: What d you want the query to do?  Sample data and desired results would help, as well as an explanation.

Comment: Why are you filtering on `cat_id` if you want `id = 2` to be in the result set?

Comment: It needs to print the thread_name of a cat_id of the highest thread_date

Answer (score 0):

Shift the portion of the `WHERE` clause restricting the `cat_id` to the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM threads
WHERE thread_date = (SELECT MAX(thread_date) FROM threads WHERE cat_id = :cat_id)
```

The subquery will now identify the maximum `thread_date` for the input `cat_id`, and the outer query will return all records sharing this maximum `thread_date`.

Comment: It still prints the thread_name of another cat_id if it has the same thread_date

Comment: You may have a problem with your data, my query should solve your problem.

Comment: No I don't have. If an column has the same thread_date it is just printing the first thread_name of it twice out.

Comment: This can't happen if there are two thread records with different names.  Again, check your data.